# ¿Cómo puedo pasar mi esquema .xsd a .xml?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, eclipse, xsd

Tengo un archivo .xsd y necesito el xml para poder hacer unas modificaciones que necesito. Como se puede hacer esto?

He estado leyendo y se supone que en eclipse da la opción siguiendo ciertos pasos pero no me deja. Alguien sabe como se puede hacer?

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/generate-xml-xsd-eclipse-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconozco si Eclipse puede realizarlo, pero NetBeans (incluído en las etiquetas de la pregunta) permite generar un "esqueleto" XML a partir de un esquema.

1. File -> New File
2. XML -> XML Document con el nombre, proyecto y carpetas deseados.
3. El tipo de documento será "XML Schema-Constrained Document"
4. En Schema Options pulsa "Browse" para seleccionar un esquema (debe estar en algún directorio del proyecto), o introduce una URL para usar un esquema remoto.
5. Selecciona los ajustes deseados para elementos opcionales (generar dichos elementos/atributos o no).

Comment: Muchas gracias @Ariel Costas